# No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.json

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

[This is the error that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvgjt.png)

I create a new react project in terminal and I get the error from the image. Can somebody tell my why I get that error and help me to fix it ?

Comment: Project is in "...../New folder/weather" so you might want to run your scripts from there. Voting to close as unreproducible or caused by typo.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me how can I fix those vulnerabilities ?

Comment: run ```npm audit fix``` from inside ```weather``` folder

Comment: I tried that and it says " fixed 0 of 86 vulnerabilities in 1929 scanned packages
  86 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated ".